# Probability - Need help with logic

Tags: probability

There are 25 boxes of yogurt and 5 of them are spoiled. What is the probability that at most 2 would be spoiled if we were to pick 5? The boxes are not replaced.

Need help walking through the logic.

Comment: find the probability that one of 5 is spoiled, then find the probability that 2 of 5 are spoiled then add probabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are obviously $\binom{25}{5}$ ways to pick $5$ yogurts our of the $25$. First, we want to find the number of ways not to pick any spoiled yogurts. Since there are $20$ unspoiled, and we want to pick $5$, the number of ways to do this is $\binom{20}{5}$. To find the number of ways to pick $1$ spoiled yogurt, we want to multiply the number of ways to pick $1$ spoiled yogurt out of the $5$ spoiled, and $4$ out of the $20$ unspoiled. Doing this, we obtain $5\binom{20}{4}$. Similarly, to pick $2$ spoiled yogurts, we want $2$ spoiled out of the $5$, and $3$ out of the $20$ unspoiled. This can be done in $\binom{5}{2}\binom{20}{3}$ ways.Adding these all together, we have:
$$\binom{20}{5}+5\binom{20}{4}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{20}{3}=51129$$
ways to pick at most $2$ spoiled yogurts. 
Since every combination of yogurts is equally likely to be picked, we have that our probability is $\frac{51129}{\binom{20}{5}}=\frac{51129}{53130}$, which reduces to $\frac{741}{770}$, and is approximately $0.962$.

Comment: While your final answer is correct, you have the probability listed as $$\dfrac{51129}{\dbinom{20}{5}}$$ but this should be: $$\dfrac{51129}{\dbinom{25}{5}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct me if I’m wrong, but if the boxes of yoghurt are being replaced after being drawn, then you would utilise binomial probabilities:

[image]

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying, the boxes are not being replaced.